# How to make bubble sort in doubly linked list?

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort, doubly-linked-list

I want to make bubble sorting algorithm with doubly linked list in python.

Node has prev key and next key.
The list connected end node and start node(head)

This is My Node defenition

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key  = key
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None
```

and this is my list def

```
class MyList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    ~~~

    def insert(self, x, y=None):
        if y is None:
            # add to tail
            if self.head is None:
              self.head = MyNode(x.key)
              self.head.prev = self.head
              self.head.next = self.head
              return True
            x.prev = self.head.prev
            x.next = self.head
            self.head.prev.next = x
            self.head.prev = x
        else:
            # insert x after y
            x.prev = y
            x.next = y.next
            y.next.prev = x
            y.next = x

    def delete(self, x):
        if self.head is self.head.prev and self.head.next:
            self.head.prev = None
            self.head.next = None
            self.head = None
            return

        node_x = self.search(x.key)
        if node_x is None:
            return

        if node_x is self.head:
            self.head = self.head.next

        node_x.prev.next = node_x.next
        node_x.next.prev = node_x.prev

    def search(self, k):
        curr = self.head.next
        while curr.key is not self.head.key:
            if curr.key == k:
                return curr
            curr = curr.next
        return curr
```

and this is swap function and sort function <- this doesnt work

```
def swap(l, x, y):
    if x == y:
        return

    node_x = l.search(x)
    node_y = l.search(y)

    if node_x is None or node_y is None:
        return

    prev_x = node_x.prev
    prev_y = node_y.prev

    l.delete(node_x)
    l.delete(node_y)

    if prev_x is not None:
        l.insert(node_y, prev_x)
    else:
        l.insert(node_y)

    if prev_y is not None:
        l.insert(node_x, prev_y)
    else:
        l.insert(node_x)

def bubble_sort(l):
    n = len(l)
    curr = l.head
    for i in range(n + 1):
        if curr.key > curr.next.key:
            swap(l, curr.key, curr.next.key)
        curr = curr.next
```

swap function doesn't work properly.
This is Error code

```
MyList.tolist(self)
     11         if x.next is self.head:
     12             break
---> 13         assert x.next.prev is x
     14         x = x.next
     16 return r

AssertionError:
```

I tried to fix swap function but it cannot work.
How to fix it?

Comment: Explain "doesn't work". What happens, what should happen? Show an error message (if any) completely as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: `curr = l.head.next` Why does the bubble sort loop skip over the first node?

Comment: @JohnGordon That is my mistake. I think swap function doesn't work properly but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Pass `curr` and `curr.next` to `swap`, not the values. Then you don't need to search for two values whose locations you already know. (Plus, if the same value occurs in the list 2 or more times, `search` may find the wrong location.)

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank for your comment. I added some of error code now.

Comment: There is much more wrong. Bubble sort does not work with one loop. You'll make it a lot easier if you swap the keys of the two nodes, instead of rewiring the two nodes out/in the list. Just leave the nodes where they are, but swap their keys.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately I don't know c++ language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

- Bubble sort needs a nested loop, yet you only have one loop
- The `swap` function is overly complex. It gets values as argument, while the caller knows what the nodes are, but leaves it for `swap` to search for them *again*.
- It deals with `None` links, but that never happens in a circular list.
- It never updates the `head` of the list, while this will be needed when one of the two given nodes is the head.
- When `node_y` is the successor of `node_x` (which is your case), then `prev_y` will be `node_x`, and so with `l.insert(node_x, prev_y)` you actually call `l.insert(node_x, node_x)`, creating havoc in the list.
- The caller executes `curr = curr.next` after the swap, but by the swap (if it would work as expected), you have already moved with `curr` one step ahead in the list, so now you skip a node.

Make the process easier (and faster) and don't rewire the nodes that need swapping, but leave them where they are: instead swap their keys.

Here is the corrected bubble sort function:

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    if not l.head:  # Nothing to do
        return 
    dirty = True
    while dirty:  # need an extra loop
        dirty = False
        curr = l.head  # need to start here
        while curr.next is not l.head:  # no need of len(l)
            if curr.key > curr.next.key:
                # swap the keys instead of the nodes
                curr.key, curr.next.key = curr.next.key, curr.key
                dirty = True
            curr = curr.next
```

If you really want to rewire the nodes, then make use of the fact that the swap is always about two consecutive nodes, so that it actually comes down to moving one node:

```
def bubble_sort(l):
    dirty = True
    while dirty:  # need an extra loop
        dirty = False
        curr = l.head  # need to start here
        while curr.next is not l.head:  # no need of len(l)
            if curr.key > curr.next.key:
                node = curr.next
                l.delete(curr)
                l.insert(curr, node)
                dirty = True
            else:
                curr = curr.next
```